# npx pod-install fails and throws very weird and long error

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, npx

I had to wipe my machine, and upon reinstalling everything I went to jump back into my React Native project. I reran yarn and it worked, but when running `npx pod-install` everything seemed to be working until a very convoluted error appeared.

I am running with the most current version of cocoapods, (installed with homebrew) and React Native Version `0.70.0`. Someone let me know if leaving my entire `package.json` would be helpful

Forgive me for the long response, but the output is as follows (after `downloading dependencies`)...

```
Installing BVLinearGradient (2.6.2)
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing EXApplication (4.2.2)
Installing EXConstants (13.2.4)
Installing EXErrorRecovery (3.2.0)
Installing EXFileSystem (14.1.0)
Installing EXFont (10.2.1)
Installing EXImageLoader (2.2.0)
Installing EXMediaLibrary (14.2.0)
Installing Expo (46.0.14)
Installing ExpoKeepAwake (10.2.0)
Installing ExpoMailComposer (11.3.0)
Installing ExpoModulesCore (0.11.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.70.0)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.70.0)
Installing Flipper (0.125.0)
Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.2.0.1)
Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.10)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.5.0.5)
Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
Installing Flipper-RSocket (1.4.3)
Installing FlipperKit (0.125.0)
Installing OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.1100)
Installing Picker (4.3.7)
Installing RCT-Folly (2021.07.22.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.70.0)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.70.0)
Installing RNCPicker (2.4.6)
Installing RNFastImage (8.6.1)
Installing RNSVG (13.2.0)
Installing RNScreens (3.18.0)
Installing React (0.70.0)
Installing React-Codegen (0.70.0)
Installing React-Core (0.70.0)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTText (0.70.0)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.70.0)
Installing React-bridging (0.70.0)
Installing React-callinvoker (0.70.0)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.70.0)
Installing React-hermes (0.70.0)
Installing React-jsi (0.70.0)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.70.0)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.70.0)
Installing React-logger (0.70.0)
Installing React-perflogger (0.70.0)
Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.70.0)
Installing ReactCommon (0.70.0)
Installing SDWebImage (5.11.1)
Installing SDWebImageWebPCoder (0.8.5)
Installing SocketRocket (0.6.0)
Installing UMAppLoader (2.2.0)
Installing UMCore (7.1.2)
Installing UMReactNativeAdapter (6.3.9)
Installing UMTaskManagerInterface (6.2.0)
Installing VisionCamera (2.14.1)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing YogaKit (1.18.1)
Installing boost (1.76.0)
Installing fmt (6.2.1)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="arm64"
    fi
fi

# @lint-ignore-every TXT2 Tab Literal
if [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "arm64" ]; then
    cat <<\EOF >>fix_glog_0.3.5_apple_silicon.patch
diff --git a/config.sub b/config.sub
index 1761d8b..43fa2e8 100755
--- a/config.sub
+++ b/config.sub
@@ -1096,6 +1096,9 @@ case $basic_machine in
                basic_machine=z8k-unknown
                os=-sim
                ;;
+       arm64-*)
+               basic_machine=$(echo $basic_machine | sed 's/arm64/aarch64/')
+               ;;
        none)
                basic_machine=none-none
                os=-none
EOF

    patch -p1 config.sub fix_glog_0.3.5_apple_silicon.patch
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

# Manually disable gflags include to fix issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28446
sed -i.bak -e 's/\@ac_cv_have_libgflags\@/0/' src/glog/logging.h.in && rm src/glog/logging.h.in.bak
sed -i.bak -e 's/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS_DISABLED/' src/config.h.in && rm src/config.h.in.bak

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

patching file config.sub
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch arm64 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/nicklanese/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-04b94/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/nicklanese/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-04b94/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/nicklanese/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-04b94':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the glog dependency issue.
Try these steps:

1. Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
2. restart terminal and do `cd ios && pod install`

This will help you solve the problem perfectly.

Comment: Can you better explain what's going on here?